# Avoid staging and deploying Javadoc for individual modules in multi-module Maven project

Tags: maven, javadoc, multi-module, maven-javadoc-plugin

I have a multi-module Maven project. I have set up the parent POM to generate aggregated Javadoc, like

```
...
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <id>aggregate</id>
            <inherited>false</inherited>        
            <reports>
              <report>aggregate</report>
              <report>test-aggregate</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
          <reportSet>
            <id>default</id>
            <reports>
              <report>javadoc</report>
              <report>test-javadoc</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
...
```

This has the effect of staging and deploying the Javadoc both as aggregated at the project level and also for the individual modules. Removing the last `reportSet` makes no difference.
Since all the information is already present in the aggregated Javadoc, I do not want it under the individual modules. How do I avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be quite simple, you define the second `reportSet` to have an empty set of reports, like

```
...
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <id>aggregate</id>
            <inherited>false</inherited>        
            <reports>
              <report>aggregate</report>
              <report>test-aggregate</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
          <reportSet>
            <id>default</id>
            <reports>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
...
´´´
```